# I'm having problems recognizing text from a picture, python

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image, python-tesseract

I was given a school project for recognizing various kinds of CAPTCHA, and I had some difficulties with its implementation.

Images of this type will be fed into input [image],[image],[image].

I handle them with the following code:

```py
import cv2 
import pytesseract 

# load image 
fname = 'picture.png' 
im = cv2.imread(fname,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) 

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

im = im[0:90, 35:150]

im = cv2.blur(im,(3,3)) 

im = cv2.threshold(im, 223 , 250, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 
im = im[1] 

cv2.imshow('',im) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

After all processing, the image looks like this:[image] And at this point, I have a problem, how can I modify the image to good readability by the computer, so that instead of the wrong `TAREQ.` he would display the `7TXB6Q`

I am trying to display text from an image with the `pytesseract` library as follows

```py
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang='eng', config='--psm 6 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist= ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
print(data)
```

I am writing here hoping to get valuable advice (perhaps you know the most suitable way to get text from a picture or process the image pinned above). Peace for everyone)

---

More images

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: If you want to read the image as grayscale, the flag should be `cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`. The flags that start with COLOR are for `cvtColor` function.

Comment: Also, please use `_, im = cv2.threshold(im, 223, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)` for clarity. Notice the maximum value is `255`, not `250`. You are not taking the green channel the next line (`im = im[1]`).

Comment: @Burak Thank you very much for your corrections, but please pay attention to the comments left under your answer, do you know what I can do?

Comment: Yes, corrections come while I'm working on it. Patience please.

Comment: @Burak I'm probably tired of you already, but below I added more photos to the question, this code works strangely with them, half of the characters are completely removed from the photo, what could it be?

Comment: Try adding a white boundary to the threshold result. [`bw = cv.copyMakeBorder(bw, 1, 1, 1, 1, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(255, 255, 255))`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga2ac1049c2c3dd25c2b41bffe17658a36) This way, I suppose those characters won't get involved in the background.

Comment: @Burak You are right as always, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try finding countours and eliminating those which have small areas. This preprocessing operation should increase the success of OCR result.

Before: [image: before]

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# your thresholded image im
bw = cv.imread('bw.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

_, cnts, _ = cv.findContours(bw, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# remove the largest contour which is background
cnts = np.array(cnts[1:], dtype=object)

areas = np.array(list(map(cv.contourArea, cnts)))

thr = 35
thr_cnts = cnts[areas > thr]

disp_img = 255 * np.ones(bw.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
disp_img = cv.drawContours(disp_img, thr_cnts, -1, (0, 0, 0), cv.FILLED)
disp_img = cv.bitwise_or(disp_img, bw)

cv.imshow('result', disp_img)
cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyAllWindows()

cv.imwrite('result.png', disp_img)
```

Result: [image: result]

---

**Edit:** It seems that merging the two codes did not give the same result. This is the full code from the beginning to the end.

Input: [image: CAPTCHA]

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# load image 
fname = 'im.png'
im = cv.imread(fname, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# crop
im = im[0:90, 35:150]

# blurring is essential for denoising
im = cv.blur(im, (3,3))

thr = 219
# the binary threshold value is very important
# using 220 instead of 219 causes loss of a letter
# because it touches to the bottom edge and gets involved in the background
_, im = cv.threshold(im, thr, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

cv.imshow('', im)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

Thresholded: [image: threshold]

```py
# binary image
bw = np.copy(im)

# find contours and corresponding areas
_, cnts, _ = cv.findContours(bw, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnts = np.array(cnts, dtype=object)
areas = np.array(list(map(cv.contourArea, cnts)))

thr = 35
# eliminate contours that are smaller than threshold
# also remove the largest contour which is background
thr_cnts = cnts[np.logical_and(areas > thr, areas != np.max(areas))]

# draw the remaining contours
disp_img = 255 * np.ones(bw.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
disp_img = cv.drawContours(disp_img, thr_cnts, -1, (0, 0, 0), cv.FILLED)
disp_img = cv.bitwise_or(disp_img, bw)

cv.imshow('', disp_img)
cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result: [image: result]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, maybe you can still advise on more working ways of recognizing text, besides `pytesseract - image_to_string`

Comment: @shalor1k Sorry, no experience on that area.

Comment: @shalor1k You know you have six letters, so you may try recognizing letters by splitting the image into six little parts. You can have a look at [`loadOCRHMMClassifier`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/df2/group__text__recognize.html#ga1d0cf1516cf8cfb2e53fdf639d547119) function for this, but Tesseract seems to be the reliable way to do it in most cases.

Comment: Yes, the number of characters is always six, but I have 350+ such pictures and the letters always move a couple of pixels, so I doubt the rationality of this method

Comment: Do you know why when you combine these two codes, they do not work correctly? The problem is that the second part of the code displays the outlines that should have been removed, and the ones that are needed, on the contrary, are removed.

Comment: But if you download and use the picture you attached, everything works great

Comment: @shalor1k I think it is because the result of your code and the thresholded image you put in the question are not the same. Not sure though. Edited for the full code. As for splitting the letters, you can again use contours. Each contour in the result is a letter, except background. The rest is up to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help you have provided, it is not common to see such responsive users. By the way, the submitted image is no different, it was taken after the algorithm was executed)